# Mousehover, tooltip showing multiple times

Tags: c#, tooltip, mousehover

I have a custom control (C#, visual studio).  I want to show a tooltip on the mousehover event.

However, no matter what I do, it either never shows or has a chance of showing multiple times.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
private void MyControl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip tT = new ToolTip();

    tT.Show("Why So Many Times?", this);
}
```

But this does not work.  I have tried a bunch of things but cannot seem to get it to work.  I would like to have the tooltip be part of the component because I want to access private fields from it for display.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried instantiating the tooltip in your constructor and showing it on the mouse hover?

```
public ToolTip tT { get; set; }

public ClassConstructor()
{
    tT = new ToolTip();
}

private void MyControl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tT.Show("Why So Many Times?", this);
}
```

Comment: This works.

However, I tried:

private ToolTip tT = new ToolTip();

outside of the mousehover event and that didn't work either.

Why is it different instantiating in the constructor rather than when it is declared?

Comment: Actually, I just tried doing it that way again and it worked.  Not sure what I screwed up the first time.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The MouseHover is fired every time the mouse moves over your control. So your are creating a new tooltip every single time the event is fired. That's why you see multiple instances of this widget. Try the Joseph's answer

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a tooltip using the designer generates wildly different code than that in the question.

Form1.Designer.cs: (private variables moved to the top of the class for readability)

```
partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;

    // ...

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Tooltip(this.components);

        // ...

        this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.label1, "abc");

        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm sure you could extract just the tooltip and container stuff into your component.

Answer (score 0):

Read MSDN it's all there!

You can try another solution:

---

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;

private void YourControl_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
     this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.YourControl, "Your text here :) ");
     this.toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
}
```

---

Hope i help